# 2 Bootstrap Login Modals With Ajax, Only 1 working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to start by saying I am very new to Ajax and just started learning, so my code might not be the best...this is quite a long question but I would like to give as much detail as possible

**My Problem**

My site has 2 login / registration options 1 on the top navbar and the second in  the middle left column

**example**

[image]
**Nav Bar 1 Registration / Login**

[image] **Nav Bar 2 Registration / Login**

*Nav1 Opens the module seen in the image below, everything working perfectly as can be seen*

[image]

My code for the login modal is as follows:

**AJAX / JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function () {
    var form = $('#regTab');
    var formMessages = $('#tabregMsg');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function (e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        //do the validation here
        if (!validateTabReg()) {
            return;
        }

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        }).done(function (response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error').addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).html(response); // < html();

            // Clear the form.
            $('').val('')
        }).fail(function (data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success').addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            var messageHtml = data.responseText !== '' ? data.responseText : 'Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.';
            $(formMessages).html(messageHtml); // < html()
        });

    });

    function validateTabReg() {
        var valid = true;

            //I have removed validation for now
        return valid;
    }
})
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="regForm" id="regTab" action="reg_upload.php" method="post">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regName">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <span  class="info"></span><br/>
        <input type="text" name="userName" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regLastName">Surname:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <span class="info"></span><br/>
            <input type="text" name="userSurname" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regEmail">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <span class="info"></span><br/>
            <input type="text" name="userEmail" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regPword">Pword:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <span class="info"></span><br/>
            <input type="password" name="userPword"  class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="confRegPword">Confirm Pword:</label>
        <span class="info"></span><br/>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" name="userPword2" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regPhone">Phone:</label>
        <span class="info"></span><br/>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="userPhone" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regCountry">Country:</label>
        <span class="info"></span><br/>
    </div>
    <button name="submit" class="btnAction" >Register</button>
</form>
```

**MY PROBLEM**

My problem comes in with the tabs...Nav Bar 2, Messages (Ajax response) should be displayed in the Tab...**It worked fine until I added the top navigation bar (nav bar 1)**

Instead of **preventing the form to submit** like it should, it goes to the page assigned to `action=""` attribute

**MY CODE FOR PILLS (NAV BAR 2 REGISTRATION)**

**AJAX / Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    var form = $('#regTab');
    var formMessages = $('#regMsg');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function (e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        //do the validation here
        if (!validateTabReg()) {
            return;
        }

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        }).done(function (response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error').addClass('success');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).html(response); // < html();

            // Clear the form.
            $('').val('');
        }).fail(function (data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success').addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            var messageHtml = data.responseText !== '' ? data.responseText : 'Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.';
            $(formMessages).html(messageHtml); // < html()
        });

    });

    function validateTabReg() {

        var valid = true;

        //SKIP VALIDATION FOR NOW

        return valid;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="frmContact">
    <div id="regMsg"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form name="regForm" id="regTab" action="reg_upload_Tabs.php" method="post">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regName">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <span id="userName-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regLastName">Surname:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">  
                    <span id="userSurname-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="userSurname" id="userSurname" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regEmail">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                    <span id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regPword">Pword:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">   
                    <span id="userPword-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                    <input type="password" name="userPword" id="userPword" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="confRegPword">Confirm Pword:</label>
                <span id="userPword2-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                <div class="col-sm-10">   
                    <input type="password" name="userPword2" id="userPword2" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="regPhone">Phone:</label>
                <span id="userPhone-info" class="info"></span><br/>
                <div class="col-sm-10">  
                    <input type="text" name="userPhone" id="userPhone" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button name="submit" class="btnAction" >Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MY QUESTION**

Why is it that the first module works (nav 1) but the pills(nav 2) using essentially almost the same code does NOT work?

***Further more when Nav1 is removed the pills Nav2 works...***

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are conflicting with `form` dom and `var form = $("#regTab")` just check that once with changing the var form to different and try hopw this solves the problem

Comment: if you once declared `var form = $("regTab")` you again using `$(form)` just try with `form.submit`  variable

Answer (score 3):

You should use different ID for your "regForm".

```
var form = $('#regTab');
```

According to explanation of jQuery and definition of javascript,

Each id element must be used only once within a document.

If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will **only select the first matched element** in the DOM.

For your reference, you can see [jQuery ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: eagle eyes huh.. :) +1 from my side

Answer (score 3):

You should have unique id in your entire document. just remove your id or make this unique.
in your form **jquery**

```
$(function () { 
    var form = $('form[name="regForm"]').closest("form"); 
     var formMessages = $('#regMsg'); // 

        // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
        $(form).submit(function (e) {
            // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
            e.preventDefault();

            //do the validation here
            if (!validateTabReg()) {
                return;
            }

            // Serialize the form data.
            var formData = $(form).serialize();
```